# Creating a shapefile within a zip file with Fiona

Tags: fiona

According to the Fiona documentation "Fiona lets you read and write zipped Shapefiles."

But I can't find any examples of writing (with Windows file paths). Trying this...

```
with fiona.open('output_shp.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema, vfs='zip://output.zip') as o:
    # Write
```

DriverError: /vsizip/output.zip/output.shp is not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add '.zip' to the filename and remove vfs.

Something like:

```
with fiona.open('output.shp.zip', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema):
```